# Login failed for user DOMAIN\PC-NAME$

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I am debugging an intranet page at the moment. I would like the page to be accessible to all people in DOMAIN, and to do this I have enabled Windows authentication, but given my connection string the username and password of an SQL account on the database with read permissions.

This is how I am printing from my table :

```
<div style="min-height: 150px; font-size: 1.25em">
    <div style="margin-bottom: .5em">
        <table><thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Branch</th><th>Phone No.</th><th>Username</th><th>Email</th></tr></thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach ( var prod in Model )
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@prod.FullName</td> 
                        <td>@prod.Branch</td> 
                        <td>@prod.PhoneNo</td> 
                        <td>@prod.DomainAC</td> 
                        <td>@prod.Email</td> 
                        @if (User.IsInRole(@"Admins") || User.Identity.Name == prod.DomainAC) {
                                <td><a href="/home/edit/@prod.Id"  style="color: blue;">edit</a></td>
                         }else{
                         <td>User => @User.ToString()</td>   
                        }
                    </tr>
                 }
                 </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
     </div>
```

So, as you can see, I want the user to be able to edit their details if the domain account they are logged in on == account in DB.

My web.config looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXXX" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" showFlags="Date, Time, Size, Extension, LongDate" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="xxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="xxxxxxxxxxxx" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.EmployeesDBModel.csdl|res://*/Models.EmployeesDBModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.EmployeesDBModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Data Source=APP1;Initial Catalog=&quot;Test Database&quot;;Integrated Security=True;user id=AnonUser;password=AnonUser;Application Name=EntityFramework'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"  />
  </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>

      <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Currently this results in :

```
Login failed for user DOMAIN\PC-NAME$

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\PC-NAME$'.
```

It occurs at the foreach in the above code extract.

What have I done incorrectly here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your connection string is ambivalent: it wants to use a username and password but, at the same time, wants to use Integrated Security (Windows Account Authentication). Since you specified `Integrated Security=True`, the user connecting to the database will be the one running the process, in this case the identity of the application pool of your website in IIS. Remove the `Integrated Security=True` and it should use the supplied user name and password instead.

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Entities" 
       connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.EmployeesDBModel.csdl|res://*/Models.EmployeesDBModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.EmployeesDBModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Data Source=APP1;Initial Catalog=&quot;Test Database&quot;;user id=AnonUser;password=AnonUser;Application Name=EntityFramework'" 
       providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"  />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Ah God, that's an embarrassing mistake ! Thanks! :)